# Show users location on map

Tags: java, android, maps, openlayers

The question might be a little general but I hope to get good ideas on how to continue.

I have created an app that has users. Let say that each user has a car and while signing-up to the app, the user has to insert the model of their car.

Then, any user can search for a car, say BMW. I had liked it to show on the map the current location of all of the users that are shown in the database as users with BMW.

I have the database that I need but my question is what is the best way to show users location on the map.

I know there is Google Maps API but it costs money so I thought to use OpenLayers but could not find any example to implement on Android.

Also, maybe there are simpler solutions to show locations on the map that I didn't hear about and If possible I had like to know.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Google Maps API on Android, you can go for OpenStreetMap. You can have a quick read to [Why use OpenStreetMap instead of Google Maps?](https://www.openstreetmap.org/user/jbelien/diary/44356)  as well.

For implementing the marker that you've asked about, use this [osmdroid](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid) Github repo. It demonstrates a map view on Android with built-in overlays for plotting icons, tracking location, and drawing shapes.

Since you have the database, to show on the map the current location of all of the users that are shown in the database as users with BMW, you use something like this:

```
ArrayList<OverlayItem> searchedCarModelList = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
items.add(new OverlayItem(userName.toString(), carModel.toString(), new GeoPoint(0.0d,0.0d)));
```

For more information, read the [wiki](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki) here and hope this helps!